# What are "Lamellenspiesse"?

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english, noun, swiss-standard-german

This meat product on a stick is called "Lamellspiess". What type of meat is it, and what is the English translation?

Comment: Worauf bezieht sich das "this"? Gibt es eine Quelle? Wo? Von der Wortstruktur ist die Einzahl "ein Spieß", die Mehrzahl "die Spieße" und "Spießen" könnte in einem Satz vorkommen, etwa "Mit den Lamellenspießen gelingt der Grillabend". Außerdem könnte es ein substantiviertes Verb sein, was aber hier wohl semantisch ausgeschlossen werden kann. "Beim alljährlichen Lamellenspießen im Grilldorf an der Sauce verletzte sich der Vorjahressieger ledier tödlich."  Das Wort ist eine Zusammensetzung aus "Lamelle" und "Spieß", d.h. der Spieß hat wohl eine Lamellenformm oder spießt etwas lamellenförmiges auf

Comment: Die Schweitzer haben kein `ß` und schreiben stattdessen immer `ss` und eine Googlesuche fördert auch v.a. Schweitzer Quellen zu Tage. Eine solche Suche kann benutzt werden, um sich über das Gerät zu informieren. Meine kurze Recherche ergab nicht, dass der Spieß nur für eine spezielle Fleischsorte geeignet ist. Das engl. Wort für "Lamelle" ist "lamella" oder "laminat" und "spit" für "Spieß", daher wäre "lamella spit" wohl die Übersetzung. Das findest Du, wenn Du nach "Lamellenspieß" suchst in jedem Wörterbuch, sobald Du "Lamelle" alphabetisch findest, und den Rest gesondert suchst.

Comment: I have never heard that word, and as userunknown writes, this is likely a Swiss word. My guess is that the word refers to the shape of the meat, not the kind of meat. If this is sold somewhere, then there should be a list of ingredients.

Comment: `ss` because Swiss

Comment: https://www.offerscheck.ch/aldi-suisse/bbq-lamellenspiess-24x9 . 
CHF1.69 for 250g in Switzerland! Probably pork I'd assume.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no interest in understanding German, it's just about edibility.

Answer (score 3):

### Lamelle

The German word *Lamelle* is *lamella* in English. It is a thin slice that exists together with other thin slices which belong together. If you cut meat in many thin slices, then it is called *Lamellen* in Switzerland.

### Spieß (in Swiss German: Spiess)

There are many translations for this word, but when we talk about cooking, then it's a *skewer.*

So, when you cut meat in thin slices and spike them on a skewer, and when you are in Switzerland, then you get a *Lamellenspiess.*

Comment: is lamelle beef, pork, lamb

Comment: @user610620: Yes: Beef, pork, lamb or what ever you want. Also chicken, turkey, duck, kangaroo, etc. Just cut it in thin slices (lamellas) and put it on a stick.

Comment: i mean, any way to tell what meat was used, if all the main label said was lamellspiess? already threw away the ingredients/plastic

Comment: @user610620: The part *»Lamelle«* tells you only that it is cut in thin slices. It doesn't tell you from which animal it was taken. If you spike cube-shaped pieces of meat on the stick, it's not a *»Lamellenspiess«.*

Comment: this makes the word overly general and completely nondescriptive. not buying it again

Comment: @user610620 *Lamelle* is in fact just as descriptive as *minced meat*, *sausage* and *medaillon* as it denominates the way of preparation. But since the packaging will still tell you which animal it is from, this need not be an obstacle for buying.

Comment: All of this would also have been my guess, but do you have any references to back this up?

Comment: @CarstenS: Ich habe gegoogelt und mehrere Anbieter von »Lamellen-Spiessen« gefunden. Die Fleischsorte wurde zwar selten angegeben, wenn doch, war es meist Schweinefleisch. Ein Anbieter bot aber auch *»Poulet Lamellen-Spiess«* an (»Poulet« ist Schweizer Hochdeutsch für »Hühnchen«). In allen Fällen war das Fleisch auf dem Spieß in Scheiben geschnitten. Kein Teil eines Schweines wird *»Lamelle«* genannt, auch nicht in der Schweiz.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Ich gebe zu, man kann sich erschließen, was das Wort bedeutet, wenn man Beispiele sieht und das Wort "Lamelle" versteht.

Comment: @user610620 you could ask a question on cooking.SE to get help to identify unknown meat. Most times it is possible to differ between beef, pork and chicken for example